# invoke object c++. Reflection in c++

Tags: c++, reflection

I am new to C++ and I'm trying to implement Reflection.

I have a Method class, Field class, and Object class.

Say, that I have an Object of Class Male called Daniel. 
The class Male has a method called increaseAge() which increases Daniel's age by 1. 
Daniel has an int field - age.

How do I invoke the Method increaseAge() on Daniel.

```
typedef void(*Func)(Object*);

class Method{
private:
    std::string nameMethod;
    Func f;

public:
    Method(std::string name,Func fun){
        nameMethod=name;
        f=fun;
    };

    /*virtual void invoke(Object* const obj);

        if Object has method, then invoke method on obj. 

        else > throw MethodNotFound. 
    */
};


#endif /* METHOD_H_ */
```

and, my main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Field.h"
#include "Method.h"

using namespace std;

void increaseAge(Object* obj){
    age++;
}


int main(){
    Method* m2 = new Method("increaseAge",increaseAge);
    Object Daniel = new Male;
    m2.invoke(Daniel);  

}
```

Comment: Put some compiling code and ask where you have difficulties. The code you posted has too many mistakes. As a side note C++ doesn't have reflection like java since it's compiled into assembly code and not byte code.

Comment: Why not using something like `std::map<std::string,std::function<void(Object*)>>`?

Comment: If you're new to a language, maybe that's not the right time to implement a reflection system.

Comment: In C++ functions and methods with the same signature are not the same type because methods implicitly get passed a this pointer.  I suggest you look up "pointer to method" and change your Method class to be a template with a pointer to method.